# How can I use a headless browser with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler, headless-browser

I'm a beginner when it comes to web development and I'm trying to crawl a webpage (a facebook for my school) using a headless browser for my app. I'm not sure where to begin with headless browsers (or basic crawling for that matter) and I'm not sure how to use it in my code to access the source code and parse through it. Any help on the matter would be super useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) library a try.  It should provide what you're looking for.

Comment: And Mechanize helps automate nokogiri (signing in/out/cookies, etc).